# Create 1 column out of 2 with retaining the 2

Tags: sql, r, merge

I have an table with 8 variables and i want to merge 2 columns named Sample and NorTum and both columns Sample and NorTum should stay in the table. Someone an idea how to do this with R or SQL? The data looks as follows:

```
    Sample  Sample_Code Sample_Group    NorTum  Sentrix_ID  Sentrix_Position    Pool_ID Folderdate
 1  00_11242    00_11242T1  MUTYH   T1  1403371 R007_C006   GS0005703-OPA   Exp051118
 2  00_11242    00_11242T1  MUTYH   T1  1403371 R007_C012   GS0005704-OPA   Exp051118
 3  00_11242    00_11242T1  MUTYH   T1  1416198 R007_C006   GS0005701-OPA   Exp051118
 4  00_11242    00_11242T1  MUTYH   T1  1416198 R007_C012   GS0005702-OPA   Exp051118
 5  00_11242    00_11242T1  MUTYH   T1  1280307 R007_C006   GS0005703-OPA   Exp051116
 6  00_11242    00_11242T1  MUTYH   T1  1280307 R007_C012   GS0005704-OPA   Exp051116
 7  00_11242    00_24200N2  MUTYH   N   1403371 R007_C005   GS0005703-OPA   Exp051118
 8  00_11242    00_24200N2  MUTYH   N   1403371 R007_C011   GS0005704-OPA   Exp051118
```

I`m sorry for the bad format of the table. But the idea for example is: Sample: 00_11242 and Nortum: T1 merge to Sample_ID so that the output looks like: Sample_ID:00_11242_T1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is called dat

```
dat$Sample_ID <- paste(dat$Sample, dat$NorTum, sep = "_")
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer sometimes you dont realise how simple it is